# VS 2010 Productivity Power Tools Disables XML Documentation on Hover

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, intellisense, productivity-power-tools

can someone verify this:

the **Visual Studio 2010 Productivity Power Tools** extension takes away XML documentation text (on mouseover or intellisense) for types and members, when you enable their "Solution Navigator"?

In other words, when I hover over a class or members, I used to see the xml documentation text (if available) which describes the type/member.  After installing the extension, the tooltip was replaced with the Solution Navigator (which is nice, don't get me wrong, but doesn't show the xml docs).

If that's a true assessment, is there a way to allow both to show up?

Answer (score 1):

The Productivity Power Tools Solution Navigator only replaces the XML documentation tooltip if you have "Enable Interactive Tooltips" checked. This menu option is available under Options -> Productivity Power Tools -> Solution Navigator -> Enable Interactive Tooltips. If you want to get your regular documentation tooltip back, just uncheck it.